# Set offset for first tick highchart xAxis

Tags: highcharts

I try to put an offset in pixel before the first tick and after the last one on the x axis.
I dont find the propertie that does this.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: There is no a built-in property to do it, but you can set min and tickPositions/tickPositioner to achieve that effect. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner